# WUP App in RC not working in RTM VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

So I created an app project (WUP) using VS 2015 RC, now I installed the RTM and the project can't be loaded, the tooltip says "The project is incompatible with the current edition of Visual Studio". Anyone crossed into this?

UPDATE: Windows 10 SDK final tools were released

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015 RTM is not compatible with the existing SDK. From the [Windows 10 developer tools preview](https://dev.windows.com/en-US/downloads/windows-10-developer-tools) page:

> Do not install Visual Studio 2015 RTM until 7/29 if you want to continue working with Windows 10 developer tool preview releases. On 7/29 the RTM releases of Windows 10 developer tools will be made available for use with Visual Studio 2015 RTM.